# Sending files via OBEX (lightblue/OBEXFTP)

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying desperately to send files via OBEX, using python. I have two functioning codes, the first using lightblue and the other using obexftp. We've got here two android phones, the first is a Samsung Galaxy S and the second is HTC desire HD (running CyanogenMod 7.1). I'm trying to send files to these phones from a computer running Ubuntu (both natty and lucid).

The thing is, each code works with only one phone. And only sometimes.

The first one is:

```
import lightblue
client=lightblue.obex.OBEXClient('MACADDR',CHANNEL)
client.connect()
client.put({'name':'file.png'},file('file.png',"rb"))
client.disconnect()
```

this one only works with the galaxy s.
If I try to send files to the desire hd I get:

```
<OBEXRespnse reason='Internal Server Error' code=0x50 (0xd0) headers={}>
```

The second code is:

```
import obexftp
cli=obexftp.client(obexftp.BLUETOOTH)
channel=obexftp.browsebt('MACADDR',obexftp.PUSH)
print channel #it is the correct channel, I've doubled checked
cli.connect ('MACADDR',channel)
cli.put_file("./file.png") #I also noticed you need to wait a second before this
cli.disconnect()
```

This one only works with the desire hd (sometimes).

All devices were paired using the bluez-simple-agent script, which is available in Ubuntu.

I'm trying to figure out what's causing this inconsistency, unsuccessfully. I'd happy if someone here point out what am I doing wrong or show me a code that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

OBEX can be notoriusly buggy, there are a lot of Headset/Handsfree manufacturers investing massive amounts of money in testing OBEX and other BT protocols...
Maybe this is the problem! Can you try more phones to test this?!